# Como configurar o jquery.maskedinput para aceitar apenas datas válidas?

Tags: jquery

Como faço para o `<input type="text" name="calendar" id="calendar">` aceitar apenas datas corretas, exemplo de uma data correta 01/02/2017 mas ele esta aceitando quando digita 01/20/2017, ou seja o mês 20 não existe, o `type` do `<input>` tem que continuar com "text", segue o exemplo com o problema.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calendar').mask('99/99/9999');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="calendar" name="calendar">
```

Comment: Por que precisa ser text?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos por que não poderia ser text?

Comment: Poderia ser "date".

Comment: Isto não é HTML5 é apenas jQuery.

Comment: @ThiagoSantos alem do caso de ser js, o type="date" não funciona no Firefox, IE e Safari: http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date

Comment: date não funciona em firefox, dessa maneira a alternativa foi utilizar a mascara jquery.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso eu escrevi uma solução (abaixo) usando JS e sem mudar de "text" que apaga o campo caso a data não exista, pode verificar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calendar').mask('99/99/9999');
  });

function validateData(){

    var dob = document.getElementById("calendar").value;
    var data = dob.split("/");

    if (isNaN(Date.parse(data[2] + "-" + data[1] + "-" + data[0]))) {
        document.getElementById("calendar").value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onBlur="validateData()" id="calendar" name="calendar">
```

Comment: resolveu o meu problema, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar usar o pattern do HTML5.

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" required />
```

Não sei se o regular expression está correta. Retirei a informação deste post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080963/html5-pattern-for-formatting-input-box-to-take-date-mm-dd-yyyy